# Get index of largest element for each submatrix in a Numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D Numpy ndarray, `x`, that I need to split in square subregions of size `s`. For each subregion, I want to get the greatest element (which I do), and its position within that subregion (which I can't figure out).

Here is a minimal example:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 10, (6,8))
>>> x
array([[9, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7, 3, 3],
       [3, 1, 8, 0, 7, 7, 5, 1],
       [7, 7, 3, 6, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [7, 3, 9, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7],
       [1, 6, 0, 7, 5, 1, 2, 0],
       [8, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 6, 0]])
>>> h, w = x.shape
>>> s = 2
>>> f = x.reshape(h//s, s, w//s, s)
>>> mx = np.max(f, axis=(1, 3))
>>> mx
array([[9, 9, 7, 5],
       [7, 9, 6, 7],
       [8, 9, 8, 6]])
```

For example, the `8` in the lower left corner of `mx` is the greatest element from subregion `[[1,6], [8, 7]]` in the lower left corner of `x`.

What I want is to get an array similar to `mx`, that keeps the **indices** of the largest elements, like this:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 2],
 [0, 2, 3, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

where, for example, the `2` in the lower left corner is the index of `8` in the linear representation of `[[1, 6], [8, 7]]`.

I could do it like this: `np.argmax(f[i, :, j, :])` and iterate over `i` and `j`, but the speed difference is enormous for large amounts of computation. To give you an idea, I'm trying to use (only) Numpy for [max pooling](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#pooling-layer). Basically, I'm asking if there is a faster alternative than what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
# Get shape of output array
m,n = np.array(x.shape)//s

# Reshape and permute axes to bring the block as rows
x1 = x.reshape(h//s, s, w//s, s).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,s**2)

# Use argmax along each row and reshape to output shape
out = x1.argmax(1).reshape(m,n)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [362]: x
Out[362]: 
array([[9, 4, 8, 9, 5, 7, 3, 3],
       [3, 1, 8, 0, 7, 7, 5, 1],
       [7, 7, 3, 6, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [7, 3, 9, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7],
       [1, 6, 0, 7, 5, 1, 2, 0],
       [8, 7, 9, 5, 8, 3, 6, 0]])

In [363]: out
Out[363]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Alternatively, to simplify things, we could use [`scikit-image`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) that does the heavy work of reshaping and permuting axes for us -

```
In [372]: from skimage.util import view_as_blocks as viewB

In [373]: viewB(x, (s,s)).reshape(-1,s**2).argmax(1).reshape(m,n)
Out[373]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```